# Exact sequence of sheaves from the exactness of sections

Tags: sheaf-theory, exact-sequence

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $\mathcal{F}_1$, $\mathcal{F}_2$ and $\mathcal{F}_3$ be sheaves on $X$. Suppose for all $U$ open in $X$ we have,

$0\longrightarrow \mathcal{F}_1(U)\longrightarrow\mathcal{F}_2(U)\longrightarrow\mathcal{F}_3(U)\longrightarrow 0$ is exact, then I think that it is not necessarily true that the sheaf sequence $0\longrightarrow\mathcal{F}_1\longrightarrow\mathcal{F}_2\longrightarrow\mathcal{F}_3\longrightarrow 0$ is exact.

But if we take direct limit over all open sets $U$ in the first sequence, since direct limit preserves exactness, we get
$0\longrightarrow\mathcal{F}_{1_x}\longrightarrow\mathcal{F}_{2_x}\longrightarrow\mathcal{F}_{3_x}\longrightarrow 0$ is exact for all $x$.

That is we have stalk level exactness, therefore the sheave sequence is exact too. Is this right?

Comment: Exactness of the sequences of sections immediately results in exactness of the sequence of sheaves. Compute each $\ker$ and $\operatorname{im}$ and verify this.

Comment: Ah thanks, it was quite obvious! Sorry for asking a trivial question.

Answer (score 7):

If the sequence $0\to \mathcal{F}_1(U)\to\mathcal{F}_2(U)\to\mathcal{F}_3(U)\to 0$ is exact for every open $U$ then the sequence of sheaves $0\to \mathcal{F}_1\to\mathcal{F}_2\to\mathcal{F}_3\to 0$ is certainly exact. What is not true is the opposite.  That is if the sequence of sheaves $0\to \mathcal{F}_1\to\mathcal{F}_2\to\mathcal{F}_3\to 0$ is exact then it doesn't follows that for every open $U$ the sequence $0\to \mathcal{F}_1(U)\to\mathcal{F}_2(U)\to\mathcal{F}_3(U)\to 0$ is exact. For example $X=\mathbb{S}^1$ (a circle), let $C^\infty$ be the sheaf of (real valued) infinitely differentiable functions on $X$ and let $\underline{\mathbb{R}}$ be the subsheaf of $C^\infty$ of constant functions (i.e. constant on every connected component), the sequence $0\to \underline{\mathbb{R}}\to C^\infty \xrightarrow{\frac{d}{dx}} C^\infty \to 0$ is exact, however the sequence of global section (for $U=X$) is not. The remedy is sheaf cohomology.